# htaccess file URL rewriting

Tags: .htaccess

For my test I have two html pages, `TEST.HTML` and `TEST2.HTML`

`TEST.HTML` has a link to go to `TEST2.HTML`:

the link is **test2.html/city/state/category**

This works fine, but when the `TEST2.HTML` page is loaded it is showing the URL as:
**test2.html?var1=city&var2=state&var3=category**

I'd like the URL to be clean, and just show:
**test2.html/city/state/category**, and not the full URL.  (does this make sense??!)

Can anyone give me some pointers on where to start? I've tried numerous different things, but it's not working.

Please let me know if you need any further info.

Here's my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test2.html/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)?$ http:/www.mydomain.com/test2.html?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

By including the domain in your rewrite destination, you are effectively instructing a redirect, and not a rewrite.

If you remove it, it will pass the arguments to the file instead, which is what you want:

```
RewriteRule ^test2.html/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)?$ test2.html?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L]
```

I've also included the `L` flag, which stops rewriting if that particular rewrite has been found.

Comment: THANK-YOU!!  THANK-YOU!!  THANK-YOU!!!!!!!!!
Something so simple!  I can't thank-you enough!!

Comment: You're welcome. Please move your other question(s) to separate threads. It's not about the mess, it's about the rules. Also, please mark the answer as correct if it helped, otherwise it sits in the unanswered queue.